# How to create a RTMP server on linux (Gentoo)

Tags: linux, gentoo, ffmpeg, rtmp

I am trying to create a RTMP server to stream video files from my Linux server to the internet/network. I have been able to successfully use ffmpeg to stream to other RTMP servers like youtube, but how do I go about hosting my own on my RTMP server locally?

I have tried looking into ffserver, but is this what I need to create a local RTMP server? If so could someone give me basic syntax or examples to get it working?

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 1):

I personally had good experiences with `crtmpserver`, it should be available in Gentoo repositories. I just followed [the tutorial on the official wiki](http://wiki.rtmpd.com/tutorial_live_stream_file).